# How to find how many sub strings can be formed from a given string?

Tags: python, string, substring

I am stuck in a condition that I have two strings:

```
#EXAMPLE 1:
S = "appleapplesre"
Y = "apple"
```

**I want to find the number of times string Y can occur in S ***without repeating any character***(i.,e., Here it occurs twice)**

```
#EXAMPLE 2:
S = "apqrctklatc"
Y = "cat"
```

Here also string Y can occurs 2 times using string S.

I have come upto this stage of coding, but am not sure how to proceed from here:

```
#Write your implementation here
S = "appleapplesre"
Y = "apple"
char_s = ''
char_y = ''

#Character count for given string S
print(S)
for char in S:
    if(char not in char_s):
        count = S.count(char)
        print(char,count)
    char_s += char
   
print()

#Character count for given string Y
print(Y)
for char in Y:
    if(char not in char_y):
        count = Y.count(char)
        print(char,count)
    char_y += char
    
if(char_y in char_s):
    print('True')

***OUTPUT:***
appleapplesre
a 2
p 4
l 2
e 3
s 1
r 1

apple
a 1
p 2
l 1
e 1
True
```

Comment: In your second example, are you looking for a `str` comparison or a `char` comparison?

Answer (score 3):

You want to find how many times you can find the characters of `Y` in `S`.

You can simply count the chars in both strings, then for each char in `Y`, calculate the ratio of its occurences in `S` by its occurences in `Y`. You answer is the smallest of these ratios.

Using a `collections.Counter`, you could do:

```
from collections import Counter

s = "apqrctklatc"
y = "cat"

s_counts = Counter(s)
y_counts = Counter(y)

repetitions = min(s_counts[char]//y_counts[char] for char in y_counts.keys())

print(repetitions)
# 2
```

Comment: lol damn nearly same answer - was working on it at the same time

Answer (score 2):

This also does the trick, building on the same logic as Thierry Lathuille:

```
S = "apqrctklatc"
Y = "cat"

repetitions = min(S.count(char)//Y.count(char) for char in set(Y))
print(repetitions)  # 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

def get_num(string, word, num=0):
    counts = Counter(string)
    word_counts = Counter(word)
    while True:
        for key, val in word_counts.items():
            counts[key] -= val
        if any([val < 0 for val in counts.values()]):
            break
        else:
            num += 1
    return num

print(get_num("appleapplesre", "apple")) #2
print(get_num("apqrctklatc", "cat")) #2
```

this take a count of how many letters you have available, and subtracts how many are required each time you take the desired word out, when the count go below 0, it means there's not enough and ends the loop